# make sure d3 data element matches id?

Tags: d3.js

I've got an existing svg with a bunch of polygons. Each polygon has a unique id, and with each id, I have some associated data.

My question is this: If I do the natural d3 join:

```
d3.selectAll("polygon").data(array_of_data)
```

Is there anyway to insure that the data element associated with a polygon is the correct one?

Or do I just need to keep the order of the `array_of_data` the same as the order of the selected polygons?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

D3's `data()` function takes an optional second argument that is intended to provide just such a correspondence between datum and DOM nodes.  Try this:

```
d3.selectAll('polygon').data(array_of_data, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

That second argument to `data()` is a callback function that, when called with a datum, returns the key that binds each DOM node to it's corresponding datum.  When you don't provide such a function, D3 is left with no option but to use the index to bind datum to DOM nodes.

Comment: how do you specify what element should match the given key? How does d3 know it's the id field that d.id should match? or does it?

Comment: All d3 does is make sure the same element is always used for a given datum.  It doesn't set the element's id attribute if that's what you're asking.  It just internally maps an element to the specified key.  If your data all have .id properties then use the code above.  If instead your data have some other way to determine the unique id, you can do that instead inside the callback, like this: `function(d) { return d.getUniqueId(); }`

Comment: so if my polygons already have a name, there's no way to tell d3 that the datum with the same name matches that polygon?

Comment: @Maus i ended up using this `data2015.forEach(function(value) { d3.select("#item-" + value.Komnr).datum(value) });`  where i essentially loops throught the data. And then selects the element and attach the data using datum(). After that i can use selectAll('path').data() as normal.